# Getting Create to work in a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Alright so I have a semi-working blog that I am trying to get comments fully functional.  Right now I have all the posts showing up correctly with all the corresponding comments with them.  The one problem with this is that you cannot actually add a comment through the site (I've just been doing it manually).

I've made "Create" methods in my Controllers previously, but only through automatic scaffolding.

Right now I pass a ViewModel to the page as follows (this grabs topics and comments associated with the blogpost itself.

```
public ActionResult Post(int id)
{
    var post = (from p in db.Set<BlogPost>()
                where p.id == id
                select new PostViewModel
                           {
                              Id = p.id,
                              Title = p.Title,
                              DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
                              Content = p.Content,
                              Topics = p.Topics,
                              Comments = p.Comments,
                              CommentCount = p.Comments.Count
                          }).Single();

    return View(post);
}
```

Then I have this as my Post.cshtml...

```
<div class="blogpost">
    <h2>@Model.Title</h2>
    <div class="post_info">@Model.DateCreated<span class="right">Blog</span></div>
    <p>@Html.Raw(Model.Content)</p>
    <div class="post_close">
        <span class="left">
            @foreach (var topic in Model.Topics)
            {
                <text>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => topic.Name) </text>
            }
        </span>
        <span class="right">
            <img src="../../Content/images/comment.jpg" alt="" />
            @if (Model.CommentCount > 1 || Model.CommentCount == 0)
            { 
                @Model.CommentCount <text>comments</text> }
            else
            {
                @Model.CommentCount <text>comment</text>
            }
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="comments">
    @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
    {
        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.Name)</b> <text>says... </text><br />
        <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.Content)</i><br />
    }
</div>
```

In the "comments" div, I want to add a way for people to create a new comment.  Obviously this wouldn't be done the traditional way with a ViewModel being the Model instead of just the Comments model.  Any advice on where to start here?

I am basically new to MVC3 and the whole idea of posting back is very confusing compared to what I was used to with web forms.  Any help would be useful, thank you!

(I will edit this post with any additional info someone may need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you haven't already, I highly recommend you start learning some jquery.  I myself would create an ajax style comments box with submit button that is only accessible for authenticated users, openid, or a custom membership provider.

You'll want to learn how to use the $.ajax and $.post methods in jquery, along with building json objects to be used with these methods.

```
<input type="textarea" id="commentBox"></input>
<input type="button" onclick="submitComment();" value="SUBMIT" />

function submitComment(){
     var newComment = {
         comment: $("#commentBox").val(),
         blogpostid: $("#PostID").val()
     }

     $.post("/BlogPost/AddComment",newComment,function(data){
           // append text to bottom of comments
           if(data.Error){
               alert(data.ErrorMessage);
           } else {
               $("#comments").append('<div id="commentDiv">' + newComment.comment + '</div'>);
           }
     });
}
```

Your BlogPost controller

```
public JsonResult AddComment(string comment, int blogpostid)
{
      // snag user info from authenticated session

      // save comment

      // return an object that has a boolean and a string it would look something like this.

      var commentResult = new object{ Error = true, ErrorMessage = 'we could not save the comment'};

      return Json(commentResult);
}
```

this doesn't cover everything and there is a lot more you will need to code both on the client and server side, including security measures.